# .slideToggle() in rails app not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add some javascript to my rails app. I am trying to do something similar to the way twitter handles youtube links in a user's tweets (when a user clicks on the tweet/video the tweet expands to show the video).

Here is what I have so far:

assets/javascripts/tracks.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show(); //not sure if needed

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

the listing of each "track"

views/tracks/_track.html.erb

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="show_hide"> <%= track.content %> </a>
  <div class="slidingDiv">
    <%= raw(youtube_embed(track.content)) %>
  </div>
</li>
```

I have a method `youtube_embed` in my helper to transform the youtube link into an embedded iframe. Could this be what is causing the `slidingDiv` to not respond to .slideToggle() ? When i go to /tracks , the youtube videos are already embedded on the page, and I can't get them to collapse. For clarity, I only want the user to see the youtube iframe after he clicks on the div.

relavent CSS (seems alright to me)

```
/* tracks */

.slidingDiv {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.show_hide {
 // display: none;
}
```

iframe that is spitted out:

```
%Q{<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/#{ youtube_id }" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>}
```

What am I doing wrong? If there is a better way of doing this - i'd love to hear it also, thank you.

Comment: This is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/UPrhN/3/ - I only made a few  minor changes so it might be something else on your page causing the issue.

Comment: You are correct sir, that jsfiddle is exactly what I want. However, I just can't seem to make it work in my rails app...

Comment: Hmmm, are there any errors in your browser's console? What other scripts are being included on the page?

Comment: You were right, apparently the '#' (comments in ruby) were what was causing the error. Quick question: Say i have an index of all the tracks - but each track has the `.slidingDiv` class, how can I use the `this` keyword in javascript to only have the track I click on expand (instead of all the tracks expanding because they have the `.slidingDiv` class. Thanks for the help Joe!

Comment: I think I got it: `$(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();` seems to be working for me...